# Get output from this code

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export, flood, change-detection

I get this error

> Error: Image. select: Pattern 'scale' did not match any bands. (Error code: 3)

from this code.

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var before = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2018-04-01','2018-05-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
.select('VV')
.min()
.clip(table);

var after = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2019-04-01','2019-05-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
.select('VV')
.min()
.clip(table);

var before = before.focal_median(100, 'circle', 'meters').rename('before');

var after = after.focal_median(100, 'circle', 'meters').rename('after');

var change = before.subtract(after).rename('change');

Map.addLayer(before,[],'before_flood',false);
Map.addLayer(after,[],'after_flood',false);
Map.addLayer(change,[],'change_map',false);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: change.select('scale'),
  scale: 10,
  description: 'change_flood',
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Check the names of your bands with `change.bandNames()`. I am almost sure there is not a band called `'scale'`, so you should change that argument in the `Export.image.toDrive`, probably to `'VV'`, or remove the `select` part.